# What is the basis for $[\mathbb{Q}(\gamma) : \mathbb{Q}]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, extension-field

Let $\gamma = e^{2 \pi i/5} + (e^{2 \pi i/5})^4
%γ = e<sup>2πi / 5</sup> + (e<sup>2πi / 5</sup>) <sup>4</sup>
$.

I am looking for the basis for $[\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$, and then looking for a dependence between $\gamma^2,\gamma$, and $1$.

I've worked all of this out by numerically but I am not sure how to do this through the basis.

Comment: Why did you use only use mathjax (the `$`-delimited text) for the title?  Use it for all mathematical expressions to make them clearer.

Comment: I have trouble reading the definition of $\gamma$, but the basic idea here is to square $\gamma$ and express it in terms of rationals and rational multiples of $\gamma.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/5}$ so that $\gamma = \omega + \omega^4$.  We note that
$$
\gamma^2 =\\
(\omega + \omega^4)^2 = \\
\omega^2 + 2\omega^5 + \omega^8 = \\
\omega^2 + 2 + \omega^3 = \\
1 + \underbrace{(1 + \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^3 + \omega^4)}_{\text{what does this come out to?}} - \gamma
$$

Answer (score 1):

A series of hints: let the suggestively named $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/5}$, so that your $\gamma=\zeta+\zeta^4$.

- What is $\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4$?  (Hint: $\frac{\zeta^5-1}{\zeta-1}=\ldots$)
- What is $\gamma^2$?
- What is $\gamma^2+\gamma$?

(This is also enough to give you an explicit expression for $\gamma$ in radicals, but you don't need that to solve the problem...)